# GMLib Waypoint abd show them

Tags: delphi-xe2, gmlib

I try this code, but the waypoints do not show

This code work perfectly, but I can't add a third spot

```
GMDirection1.DirectionsRequest.Origin.Address := 'My spot 1';
GMDirection1.DirectionsRequest.Destination.Address := 'My spot 2';
GMDirection1.Execute;
```

But this one, not at all

```
GMDirection1.DirectionsRequest.WaypointsList.Add.Location.Address := 'My spot 1';
GMDirection1.DirectionsRequest.WaypointsList.Add.Location.Address := 'My spot 2';
GMDirection1.DirectionsRequest.WaypointsList.Add.Location.Address := 'My spot 3';
// or GMDirection1.AddWaypoint.Location.Address := 'My spot';
// I try all Waypoint.Add unsuccessful
GMDirection1.Execute;
```

My map remains desperately empty
Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
GMDirection1.DirectionsRequest.Origin.Address := 'My spot 1';
GMDirection1.DirectionsRequest.Destination.Address := 'My spot 3';
GMDirection1.DirectionsRequest.WaypointsList.Add.Location.Address := 'My spot 2';
GMDirection1.Execute;
```

Regards